# CSV lines as key/values in a dictionary

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

Imagine a CSV that looks like

```
Zipcode  State
0000     CA
0001     CA
```

I want to create a dictionary where the Key is the zipcode and the Value is the State.

I've already written a function that reads the CSV line by line,

```
for i, line in enumerate(reader):
    print ('line[{}] = {}'.format(i, line))

output: 
line[1] = ['0000', 'CA']
line[2] = ['0001', 'CA']
```

How do I take each line and make it an entry in dictionary?
Hoping for an output as return `dict[zipcode]`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. This isn't a discussion forum or  Tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already made an iterator over parsed lines you can just use a dictionary comprehension to get what you want.

```
{line[0]: line[1] for line in reader}
```

Comment: is this all I have to write? how do i use the dictionary comprehension? it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: How is it not working for you?  I'm unable to reproduce any problems you are having because I don't know how your `reader` variable is defined.

Comment: My code is `import csv
with open('ZIPCODE.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
   reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter="\t")

   for i, line in enumerate(reader):
       print ('line[{}] = {}'.format(i, line))
mydict = {line[0]: line[1] for line in reader}`

Error I get: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 11, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 11, in <dictcomp>
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.` Line 11 = `{line[0]: line[1] for line in reader}`

Comment: It looks like that when you `enumerate(reader)` you're consuming the iterator returned by `csv.reader`.  So when you go to use that iterator for the dictionary comprehension there are no lines left to comprehend over.  Also if you try to access the reader outside of the `open` context you'll get that I/O error.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach using `pandas.read_csv`

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv(file_path)
df.set_index('Zipcode').T.to_dict(orient='records')[0]
```

OUTPUT:

```
{'0000': 'CA', '0001': 'CA'}
```

Comment: thanks! is there another way without pandas?

Comment: There is but i think this is the most efficient (takes least amount of time)